# Konjunktiv 2 Plural von kennen

Tags: grammar, verb, subjunctive

Neulich las ich in der "Zeit" einen Satz, der mich im Lesefluß stocken ließ. Ich kann mich nicht genau an den Satz erinnern, daher hier eine "in etwa-e" Wiedergabe:

> Die Behauptung vieler Politiker, sie kennten sich aus....

Meine ursprünglichen Fragen waren diese:

- Ist dies tatsächlich der "synthetische" Konjunktiv 2 von kennen?
- Ist es normal, diesen zu benutzen, oder wäre die analytische Version "würde kennen" vorzuziehen?

EDIT:

- Wäre eine Verwendung des Konjunktiv 1 auch vorstellbar? Es würde in meinen Ohren sogar natürlicher klingen ohne den "indirekte Rede" Moment zu verlieren.

Comment: Canoo.net kennt die Form auch: http://www.canoo.net/inflection/kennen:V:haben

Comment: Zur dritten Frage: Der Konjunktiv I ist hier ja mit dem Indikativ identisch (_sie kennen sich aus_). Gerade wenn man offenbar den Wahrheitsgehalt anzweifelt, braucht man schon etwas, das die indirekte Rede kenntlich macht.

Comment: Das ist mir klar, aber erstens ist indirekte Rede durch das Wort "behauptung" mehr als nur impliziert und ich höre den Konjunktiv 1 mit wenn ich einmal in die Richtung denke... kennten hingegen stört mich einfach nur, da ich dieses Wort defacto nicht kenne... abr das ist nur meine Meinung

Comment: Auch wenn ich im eigenen Sprachgebrauch zu "kennen würde" tendiere, so ist es doch für mich absolut einwandfrei lesbar. Kein Holperstein.

Comment: "kennten" ist mir noch nie untergekommen. Entweder ausgestorben oder nur außerhalb von Deutschland verwendet. "..., sie würden sich auskennen ..." ist gebräuchlich

Comment: Ich gehe mit *Em1*. Ich hab `kennten` wie erwähnt im Ohr. Es wurde mir somit vermutlich zu Hause, in der Schule, und sonstwo eben so antrainiert. Aber dem Konjunktiv II gehts wohl wie dem Genitiv.

Comment: @alk: äh... wem?

Comment: @Emanuel: Ich kann nicht folgen. Was ist unklar?

Comment: @alk: Das war ein Scherz... von wegen Genitiv und so ;)

Comment: @Emanuel: Achso, sorry, das schnallt der kleine Autist in mir latürnich nicht. S-)

Comment: @alk Genitiv ins Wasser, weil es Dativ ist.

Comment: ist wirklich am Aussterben: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kennte&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: @falkb: Das kann man m.E. aus dem Ngram nicht entnehmen. Die Zahlen sind schon Verhältnisse, wobei ich nicht weiss welche genau - Vorkommnisse pro Text, pro Seite, pro Satz oder Wort? Jedenfalls aber jeweils zu ihrer Zeit. Heute ist der Quotient etwa 1/8 so hoch wie um 1800. Wenn aber in der gleichen Zeit der Textkonsum/die Textproduktion um mehr als das 8fache zugenommen hat - das halte ich für gut möglich - kommt man heute summa summarum häufiger mit dem Wort in Kontakt als anno dunnemals. Es stirbt also nicht aus.

Comment: @user unknown: Es ist auf Wörter bezogen. Wenn du 1820 eine Textmenge von zehn Million Wörter in damals aktuellen Büchern gelesen hast, bist du 28mal auf _kennte_ oder _kennten_ gestoßen (plus ein weiteres Mal auf _kenntest_ oder _kenntet_). Unter zehn Millionen Wörtern aus dem Jahr 2000 gab es gerade noch knapp 4 Vorkommen von _kennte_ oder _kennten_ und 0,1 von _kenntest_ oder _kenntet_. – Zum Vergleich: _Geomantik_ ist über die letzten fünfzig Jahre etwa gleich häufig.

Comment: @chirlu: Für das Aussterben ist aber nicht die relative Häufigkeit entscheidend, sondern die absolute. Solange die absolute Zahl wächst wird man kaum von einem Aussterben sprechen können.

Comment: Quatsch, wenn der Anteil sinkt, wird es durch anderes ersetzt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Kennen* gehört zu einer kleinen Gruppe von Verben (mit *brennen*, *rennen* und *nennen*), die zwar schwach konjugiert werden, aber im Präteritum und im Partizip Perfekt den Stammvokal zu *a* wechseln:

> ich kannte, wir nannten, ein gebranntes Kind, sie sind gerannt

Alle anderen Formen sind vollkommen regelmäßig gebildet und haben ein *e*. Somit lautet auch der Konjunktiv II *kennte*, *kenntest*, *kennten*, *kenntet*. Das ist insofern ungewöhnlich, als er bei schwachen Verben sonst mit dem Präteritum zusammenfällt:

> Selbst wenn man sie trennte, würde das nichts ändern.
>   Man trennte sie, was nichts änderte.

Vermutlich deshalb sind die Konjunktiv-II-Formen von *kennen* usw. noch weniger „im Ohr“ als bei anderen Verben und werden noch stärker gemieden, d.h. meistens mit *würde* umschrieben. Es sind aber die historisch korrekten Formen (Belege bei Schiller und Goethe in [einem Artikel der GfDS-Sprachberatung](http://www.gfds.de/sprachberatung/fragen-und-antworten/uebersichtsseite/konjunktiv-von-kennen/); Link beigesteuert von Wrzlprmft), die auch – in den letzten Jahrzehnten stetig abnehmende – Verwendung in der späteren Literatur finden ([Statistik aus dem Google-Books-Corpus](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kennte%2Ckennten&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=2); Auswertung, modifiziert, nach falkb).

---

Zur nachgeschobenen Frage (die eigentlich nicht hierher gehört, weil sie nicht spezifisch für *kennen* ist), verweise ich auf [diese Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/6292), die es recht genau trifft.

Im Singular wäre Konjunktiv I normal („Seine Behauptung, er kenne sich aus“), im Plural bleibt – wegen des Zusammenfalls von Konjunktiv I und Präsens – nur Konjunktiv II („Ihre Behauptung, sie kennten sich aus“) oder die *würde*-Form („Ihre Behauptung, sie würden sich auskennen“). Indikativ wäre jedenfalls für einen Artikel in der *Zeit* falsch – da würde ich mein Abo kündigen, wenn ich es noch hätte.

Comment: Zur Antwort auf die nachgeschobene Frage: 1) Es gibt keine Pflicht, den Konjunktiv Ⅰ durch den Konjunktiv Ⅱ zu ersetzen, wenn er mit dem Indikativ zusammenfällt (auch wenn es häufig empfehlenswert ist). 2) Der Wortlaut des Beispielsatzes legt nahe, dass hier der Irrealis (Konjunktiv Ⅱ) beabsichtigt ist, um zu unterstreichen, dass eine falsche Behauptung wiedergegeben wird (und Politiker sich also in Wirklichkeit gar nicht auskennen).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Was heißt schon Pflicht? Normative Grammatiken sind arg aus der Mode gekommen. :) Trotzdem schreibt die _Duden_-Grammatik, der Konjunktiv sei in einem nicht mit _daß_ eingeleiteten Satz „zwingend gefordert, weil er … das einzige Merkmal für die indirekte Rede ist“. Das kann man auch auf die Wahl von Konjunktiv II übertragen, wo die _Duden_-Grammatik sich allerdings zurückhaltender ausdrückt. – Daß eine stärkere Distanzierung vom Inhalt beabsichtigt ist, kann natürlich sein; wir kennen ja den weiteren Kontext nicht. Dann aber erst recht kein Indikativ.