# kennte vs. kännte

Tags: spelling, subjunctive

Wie bereits in [einer anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7762/konjunktiv-2-plural-von-kennen) angesprochen, ist *kennte* eine korrekte (wenn auch etwas aus der Mode gekommene) Konjunktiv-Ⅱ-Form von *kennen* und analoge Formen existieren für *rennen, nennen* und *brennen.*

Intuitiv schriebe ich diese Form aber *kännte,* da der Konjunktiv Ⅱ ja durch Umlautung des Präteritums gebildet wird (vgl. *geben → gab → gäbe; haben → hatte → hätte*). Und auch die Rechtschreibregeln sagen hierzu:

> Für kurzes [ɛ] schreibt man ä statt e, wenn es eine Grundform mit a gibt.  (§ 13)

Hier gibt es mit *kannte* eine Grundform mit a, keine Ausnahmeregelung greift und das Wort taucht nicht in der Wortliste auf, also müsste es *kännte* sein. (Man könnte sich jetzt zwar auf den Standpunkt stellen, dass die Imperfektform keine Grundform sei, aber dann müsste man z. B. auch *schwemme* statt *schwämme* schreiben.)

Hingegen empfiehlt z. B. der [Dudens](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kennen) die Schreibung *kennte* und diese Schreibung ist auch stark vorherrschend ([Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kennte+%2B+rennte+%2B+brennte+%2B+nennte%2Ck%C3%A4nnte+%2B+r%C3%A4nnte+%2B+br%C3%A4nnte+%2B+n%C3%A4nnte&year_start=1800&year_end=2013&corpus=20&smoothing=0)). **Wieso?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eine Perspektive: Bei schwachen Verben wird der Konjunktiv II nicht durch Umlaut aus dem Präteritum gebildet, sondern direkt aus dem Stamm. Normalerweise ist er mit dem Präteritum identisch: *sagte*, *rettete*, *rollte*. Durch den Vokalwechsel fallen bei *kennen* und Co. Präteritum und Konjunktiv II auseinander, aber es gibt keinen Grund, den Konjunktiv II anders zu schreiben als den Infinitiv oder das Präsens.

Andere Perspektive: Das *e* im Stamm von *kennen*, *brennen* usw. ist historisch durch Umlautung eines *a* entstanden. Insofern wäre es folgerichtig, *kännen*, *sie kännt*, *wir kännten* zu schreiben, wie auch *Ältern* eigentlich die logische Schreibung wäre (Stammprinzip). Man tut es nicht, weil diese Stämme nicht erkannt wurden, als sich die Schreibung herausbildete, und man sich auch bei der Rechtschreibreform nicht an eine Änderung dieser vertrauten Schreibweisen herantraute; technisch ist das geregelt in § 15 der Amtlichen Regelung:

> In wenigen Wörtern schreibt man ausnahmsweise *e*.

Comment: Sprich: Die entsprechenden Wörter wurden in der Ausnahmeliste des Regelwerks schlichtweg vergessen …

Answer (score 7):

Nicht nur seit der letzten Rechtschreibereform wundert man sich über die eigenartige Bildung des Konjuntivs von *kennen*. Schon die [Grimms schrieben in ihrem Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GK03542):

> der conj. zu *kannte* heiszt *kennte*, es ist aber zu verwundern, dasz man nicht auf *kännte* gedrungen und es durchgesetzt hat [...].

Wahrscheinlich hat einfach niemand *"kännte"* benutzt und daher wurde es auch nie eingeführt. Das Warum bleibt aber unbeantwortet. Man wollte es vielleicht auch deshalb nicht in einer Rechtschreibreform über die Köpfe der Leute hinweg durchsetzen. Das erscheint mir zumindest vernünftig.