# Which verb form when using infinitive with subjunctive I

Tags: verb, subjunctive, infinitive, indirect-speech

Which rule has priority? **Infinitiv** / **Konjunktiv (I)**

> Sie behauptet, eine gesetzliche Vorgabe zur Einschließung der Nummern
>   nicht zu **<s>wisse</s> kenne**

*vs.*

> Sie behauptet, eine gesetzliche Vorgabe zur Einschließung der Nummern
>   nicht zu **<s>wissen</s> kennen**

Comment: A better choice than *wissen* would be *kennen* in this context. Also, *Vorgabe* is feminine so you need *eine.* Since both issues are minor and not relevant to the question asked, I corrected them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction in your example is called *Infinitiv mit „zu”*, and therefore it would be grammatically correct to say

> Sie behauptet, eine gesetzliche Vorgabe zur Einschließung der Nummern nicht **zu wissen**.

However, the sentence sounds odd. First, instead of *zu wissen* it should be *zu kennen*; and second, *zur Einschließung* is a bureaucratic lingo of *zum Einschließen* or *zum Einschluss*. A better formulation would be

> Sie behauptet, eine gesetzliche Vorgabe zum Einschluss der Nummern nicht zu kennen.

The construction using *Infinitiv mit „zu”* can be converted in a construction with *Konjunktiv I*

> Sie behauptet, sie **kenne** keine Vorgabe zum Einschluss der Nummern.

or, alternatively,

> Sie behauptet, dass sie keine Vorgabe zum Einschluss der Nummern **kenne**.

When you know that the statement is wrong, you can also use *Konjunktiv II*

> Sie behauptet, sie **kennte** keine Vorgabe zum Einschluss der Nummern.

or, equivalently,

> Sie behauptet, dass sie keine Vorgabe zum Einschluss der Nummern **kennte**.

Comment: Usually, in the case of "kennen" (and other -ennen verbs), you'd use "würde kennen" instead of "kennte". "Kennte" is often avoided. Further information: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/7926/28850

Answer (score 3):

Correct is:

> Sie behauptet, eine gesetzliche Vorgabe zur Einschließung der Nummern nicht zu **kennen.**

If you want to use Konjunktiv, you can write this:

> Sie behauptet, sie **kenne** keine gesetzliche Vorgabe zur Einschließung der Nummern.

or

> Sie behauptet, dass sie keine gesetzliche Vorgabe zur Einschließung der Nummern **kenne**.

Answer (score 2):

An infinitive construction is not considered reported speech in a subordinate clause. So it cannot be transformed into a subjunctive I. The only correct way to say it is:

> Sie behauptet, eine gesetzliche Vorgabe zur Einschließung der Nummern nicht zu **kennen.**

You can tell this is an infinitive from the *zu* before the verb. A construction employing a subordinate clause would be e.g:

> Sie behauptet, dass sie eine gesetzliche Vorgabe zur Einschließung der Nummern nicht **kenne.**

Note how this clause is introduced by the conjunction *dass* and that there is no *zu.*